# jasper pdf report does not show up

Tags: pdf, jsf-2

my JSF 2.0 web application is intended to produce PDF reports.
the problem is that no PDF report is shown up in the explorer window.
I am using eclipse kepler, with apache-tomcat-7.0.52 and the version of jasper Ireport is 4.8
any help would be appreciated.

I will provide the whole java class :

```
   package khldqr.beans;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;


@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped

public class TestReport  {

    private List<Refugee> refugee;  


    public List<Refugee> connectRefugeeData() {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        Connection con = Database.getConnection();
        String stm = "Select R_NO, F_P_Name from M_MAIN_INFO where R_NO < 10";

        refugee = new ArrayList<Refugee>();

        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(stm);
            pst.execute();
            rs = pst.getResultSet();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Refugee refugeelist = new Refugee();
                refugeelist.setR_NO(rs.getInt(1));
                refugeelist.setF_P_Name(rs.getString(2));

                refugee.add(refugeelist);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return refugee;
    }

        public void PDF(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException, JRException {
            System.out.println("this is not my lucky day!!!!!");
            File jasper = new File(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("report/Majd.jasper"));
            byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasper.getPath(),null,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(refugee));
            HttpServletResponse response =(HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0 , bytes.length);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        }

    public TestReport() {
    connectRefugeeData();
    }

    public List<Refugee> getRefugee() {
        return refugee;
    }

    public void setRefugee(List<Refugee> refugee) {
        this.refugee = refugee;
    }

}
```

and here is xhtml file:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Hello To GOPA World!!</title>

</h:head>

<h:body dir="rtl">


               <h:form>
                <p:commandButton value = "PDF" actionListener="#{testReport.PDF}"></p:commandButton>
                 </h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{testReport.refugee}" var="var">
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{var.r_NO}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>

    <h:column >
      <h:outputText value="#{var.f_P_Name}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

</h:body>
</html>
```

I can see the message on the console and the page gets refreshed but no PDF report is come up the explorer screen

I have replaced the above PDF method  with the code below, but in vain, the same result:  no PDF report is coming up the explorer screen.

```
   JasperPrint jasperPrint;
      public void init() throws JRException{
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(refugee);
    String  reportPath= "e:\\Rita.jasper";
    jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, new HashMap(),beanCollectionDataSource);
        }


       public void PDF(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws JRException, IOException{
           init();
           HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse=(HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        //  httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().setResponseContentType("‌​application/pdf");
           ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream=httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
           JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, servletOutputStream);
           System.out.println("All done the report is done");
           servletOutputStream.flush();
           servletOutputStream.close(); 
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
       }
```

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Comment: thx for your quick reply and sorry for missing these!!.
the program is eclipse , the server is tomcat 7 , jasper version is 4.8 and the programming language is is jsf 2.0

Comment: **UPDATE** when I substitute
the component  'p:commandButton' with 'h:commandButton' 
and the attrib 'ationListener' with 'action'
the console message does not show also, which mean that the action is not invoked. any suggestions!? please..!!!

Answer (score 0):

the code is correct, and there is nothing wrong with it.
the problem was some kind of security issue.
I faced the above problem when the report was in a full access folder to all users.
put when I put both of the requested xhtml and the report in a secured folder, everything went OK.
I don't know why!! but that was the case with me.
hoping others will make use of this.
thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:commandButton value = "PDF" actionListener="#{testReport.PDF}" ajax="false" type="submit"></p:commandButton>
```

you cant use ajax when calling jasperReports